# Hide Interface from assembly

Tags: c#, .net, interface, architecture, access-levels

I have one architectural problem,

problem diagram [image]

I develop some API (DLL) which be published for any users and a separate desktop app for configuring data for use by this API in users apps, but I need to hide **Set*** methods of DataBaseAccess class from users.

In the diagram, I showed how I imagine the separation of interfaces, entities and the access level to the database from the API and the editor. But in any case, the IRepository interface will be visible in the API and in the user applications, which I am trying to avoid.
In other words, "no access interfaces for API users, only access methods from the API itself".
All interfaces just leak through references now.

Please, help me hide interfaces from users.

Comment: I found a solution, made the interfaces internal and marked it with the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute].
For IEntitySource "friends" is DataAccess and API assembly, for IRepository - DataAccess and Editor assembly.
Please rate this solution, I'm not sure if this is the "correct" approach .